# Check if a moment contains a time?

Tags: momentjs

I'm trying to determine if a moment object was instantiated with a time value (in addition to a date). For example:

```
var date = moment("2014-01-16");
date.format("h:mm a"); // 12:00 am
```

and

```
var date2 = moment("2014-01-16 09:30");
date.format("h:mm a"); // 9:30 am
```

How can I ask `date` if it contains a time (and not just a default value)?

Comment: There are projects which use a workaround for this problem. As an example, refer to the Fullcalendar node module: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/#ambiguously-timed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well technically, the constructor that passes only a date IS instantiating it with a time, 12:00:00, even though it is implicit. Even so, here are some possible solutions.

From least safe and least work to most safe and most work:

1) Check if it's exactly equal to 12:00:00 and assume it was not set. Bad approach if your use-case has things happening around midnight often.

2) Don't ever instantiate a moment without explicitly specifying the time.

3) Wrap moment in a custom object, or create an entirely new custom object, capable of representing the null time case (a flag, nullable variable, etc.)

Comment: Thanks Dan, I'm currently using method 1, but I'm looking for something more robust. I'm not sure I want to go so far as creating a custom object though as I'm not sure I want to tackle all the edge cases of parsing times from possible datetime inputs... and I'd rather midnight be an acceptable value if possible. even if uncommon.

Comment: I would use 3a: a moment wrapper. It has two members, a moment, and a bool nullTime. The constructor only has to do enough parsing to determine if the input contains a time and set the nullTime flag to true if it does not.

Comment: So I think what I'm going to do is use method 1 but then check the value of the `moment._i` which holds the value passed to the constructor. If that value contains 00:00:00 then that was passed explicitly, else it was set by moment's constructor. This approach won't work for moments constructed like `var d = moment()` but that doesn't apply in this case. Any reason this would be a bad idea?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach to me!